# Using Password-Protected SSH Keys for Unattended Scripts on Remote Server

Tags: ssh, bash, authentication, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

From PC1, I SSH into **SERVER1** where I have a bash script, that will SSH & auth to **SERVER2** using an SSH-key that's password-protected.

Everything works fine when I manually execute my script, using ssh-agent to load my password-protected key into memory and forwarding it to **SERVER2** for auth.

But using crontab on SERVER1 it routinely fails; how can I get the following command to work using a password-protected SSH key?

`SERVER1$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/somekey.pem SERVER2`

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The idea of password-protecting the keys is that every time the key is read, the password needs to be supplied. When running the command automatically, there is nothing which could provide the necessary password, so `ssh` won't get access to the private key.

It is possible to circumvent this, using some kind of automation which does provide the password from code (using `expect` for example), but that way, you would have to save the password somewhere in order to feed it to `ssh`. So you password-protect the key, but provide the password right away, so what's the point?

I think it is better to have a passwordless key for automated tasks.